# Payment Methods on Website

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, braintree, mobile-application

I am using **braintree** in our apps to accept payments from **credit/debit cards and paypal**.

But I also want to use braintree on my website. I am using **php Laravel framework 5.2 .**

How can I enable my website to accept payments from braintree paypal and credit/debit cards?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and indicate where is the problem in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel offers the Cashier package for integration with Stripe and Braintree.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/billing